# Connect mongoDB atlas to application using VPC without username password

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, mongodb-atlas, database-security, network-security

I have one mongo db hosted in AWS atlas account and my application is running in AWS EC2 instance. I want to access my DB using my application by VPC peering but it always ask for username password which i think is not a good practice because for this i need to hardcode dummy credentials in properties file.

Is there any way I can do this without using dummy credentials. Can I do this using private endpoint? Please suggest best practice used in industry for mongodb atlas.

Answer (score 1):

Authentication is orthogonal to your network topology (VPC).

Authentication in Atlas is required. You can try using x.509 or aws authentication instead of passwords.